# How to setup apache to serve both a rails app and a full php app at the same DocumentRoot

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess

Could not figure out how to frame question better..

What I am trying to do is get Rails and php to work together. My php code is in `public`folder, and my apache is using `public` folder as the DocumentRoot. I have `puma` running on :3000. I am trying to use `Rewrite` rules as I saw on a [blog post](http://vincecima.com/2013/08/17/apache-and-puma-and-rails-configuration.html), to forward to `puma` when appropriate.

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://0.0.0.0:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

However I have a `index.php` sitting at the root I want to pass through. What would be the best way? I tried a bunch of different things, but cant get any to work fine

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

Doesnt work at all,

While

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
```

as you can imagine catches every url.

By doesnt work I mean I get `No route matches [GET] "/index.html"` on my rails server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected I had missunderstood the problem. After apache receives the `/` it rewrites (?) it to various index files and tries them in turn. Thus I had to prevent each of those from triggering my rewrite so that apache finally gets to `index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.cgi
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.pl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://0.0.0.0:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

With these rules it works on my local, hopefully will run on my server as well. I will update the question to be better related to the material.